# Where are you, Sammy Wolfe…?

Tags: knowledge, visual, rebus, situation

Adventurer and photographer Sammy Wolfe built a solar-powered airplane to explore the North American wilderness. Unexpectedly, the engine stopped working and he was forced to land his plane in the middle of nowhere. Unfortunately, he was unable to repair the aircraft. “I’m in a terrible fix! I don’t even have a telephone to call for help.”

Later on, he met a lone hermit named Alfred who shared some of the little food he had so Sammy could survive. Alfred eventually came up with the idea to attach a secret message to a large helium balloon. Whoever finds it, reads it, deciphers it and comes to save the daring adventurer shall be rewarded with precious gold that Alfred inherited from his ancestors.

You just found Sammy’s message during your stroll in the fields, wondering what the peculiar drawings mean. Out of curiosity, you are determined to solve the mystery. The first part of the message is as follows:

[image: first part of the message]

The message goes on as follows:

[image: second part of the message]

You also find a handwritten note stating that Sammy is stranded about 58 miles north of where the road turns sharply to the north-east, according to his GPS and maps.

After deciphering the drawings, you should be able to determine the approximate **geographical coordinates** of where Sammy is.

---

### Hints

Take a look at the following hints only if you are stuck—no cheating please.

1. > If you cut an image, cut what it stands for literally.
2. > The ✕ in “⨂DD” negates the word.
3. > The symbol ♂ can either mean “male” or “masculine.”
4. > The second row of the second part gives you three numbers which indicate which bytes to extract.
5. > The number stands for the road, the two letters stand for the area. Remember we are looking for a place somewhere in North America!
6. > You don’t need to do any hexadecimal, octal or decimal conversions.
7. > Look at each image or symbol carefully because they tell you what to do: abc → 01100001 01100010 01100011 → 11000110 01000110 10000110 → pick #2 → 01000110 → **?**
8. > *“[…] where the road turns sharply to the north-east […]”*
   > [image: map and compass]

Comment: Do you have a larger picture of the yellow flower?  I'm struggling to identify it due to the poor resolution of the image.   Is it a rot13(cevzebfr)?

Comment: @LOTGP Yes, that’s right.

Comment: rot13(Qbrf n flzoby orvat fcyvg va unys arprffnevyl zrna gung vg unf na rira ahzore bs yrggref?  V pna'g frrz gb svther bhg jung gur obggbz yrsg flzoby zrnaf, nf gur bayl vagrecergngvba V unir jvgu na rira ahzore bs yrggref vf [srz]nyr, juvpu vfa'g hfrshy.  V nffhzr gung vg'f fhccbfrq gb tvir hf n fgngr/cebivapr?)

Comment: @LOTGP rot13(Va guvf pnfr, lrf. Gur flzoby ersref gb n jbeq fvzvyne gb “srznyr.” Naq lrf, vg unf fbzrguvat gb qb jvgu gur fgngr/cebivapr jr ner ybbxvat sbe, ng yrnfg vaqverpgyl.)

Comment: rot13(ner lbh pbhagvat fcnprf nf cneg bs gur grkg?)

Comment: @LOTGP rot13(Lrf, lbh arrq gb vapyhqr gur fcnprf.)

Comment: I updated my answer, I think it should be complete now?

Comment: @Surma where is @user47620? I cannot see him anywhere.

Comment: @1357924680a They deleted their account.  Account names of the form user(number) usually signify a deleted account, as their previous name gets removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*First note:*

> p(l)ea se[at] gi[ft] [lo]ve

> hi m [blo]som et hing[e]

> [na]to e a t

*Thus the message is:*

> Please give him something to eat

*Second note:*

> text -> bin [can]ary -> reverse it

> [femi]nine <- 23 <- extract a prim[rose] e el even

*Thus:*

> text -> convert to binary -> reverse it -> extract the following bytes: 11th prime (31) -> 23 -> 9

*When we follow the steps outlined above:*

> Convert the first message into binary, reverse it, and extract the 3 bytes from the result, we end up with the bytes: 00110110, 01101110, and 01110110.  When converted back to text, we get the string: 6nv.

*Thus, the road Sammy is referring to is:*

> US Route 6 through Nevada.

*Finally, we go up 58 miles from where the road turns NE to find Sammy at:*

> [Savory Mountain](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Savory+Mountain/@38.7794262,-116.4746614,8.95z/data=!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x80bae7f2571ade49:0x4d40788b658426ff!2sNinemile+Peak!3b1!8m2!3d39.146876!4d-116.2508967!3m4!1s0x80bae1e03a45c0c3:0x2c1bdf2db5d27b46!8m2!3d39.0541013!4d-116.418407)

**Coordinates:**

> 39.0541° N, 116.4184° W

I guess Alfred doesn't have much of a sweet tooth.

Comment: rot13(Znlor gur # fvta ercerfragf 'fvta ynathntr', cbffvoyl n fvta sbe 'svaq/qvfpbire'? Znlor 'RRY ab bqq' ercerfragf 'R', cbffvoyl tvivat CEVZ+R = CEVZR?
V svefg gubhtug gur gerr zvtug or GERR - ynfg 2 = GE, tvivat 'GENYR' (Genvy), ohg frrzf hayvxryl tvira gur erfg, lbhe nafjre bs 23 znxrf zber frafr.)

Comment: Looks like a good start :) A couple of corrections to your initial message derivation: rot13(fr[ng] abg fr[nz] naq tv[sg] abg tv[ir] - bgurejvfr jr jbhyqa'g arrq gb nygre gung jbeq ng nyy! Oybffbz nyfb unf gjb f'f - abgr gung vg'f npghnyyl n yvggyr zber guna unys gung'f oynaxrq bhg...)

Comment: rot13(V rffragvnyyl whfg thrffrq ba gur frnz/frng bar, nf V xarj jung gur yrggref unq gb or, ohg ab vqrn jung gur vzntr ercerfragf.  GOU V fgvyy qba'g ernyyl frr ubj vg zrnaf n frng.  Gur tvir bar vf n glcb, V unq vg nf tvsg, ohg V thrff nf V xarj gur svany jbex jnf tvir, V nppvqragnyyl glcrq gung vafgrnq.)

Comment: It's a [car brand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SEAT) :)

Comment: I thought it looked kinda like a logo.   I appreciate your feedback on the first note.  Admittedly I'm a bit stuck on the second one, have I gotten anything major wrong, or do I just need to stare harder at the things I've translated so far and hope something clicks?

Comment: rot13(QRP zvahf gjb vf BPG juvpu V nffhzr jvyy cebir hfrshy gbjneq gur raq).

Comment: Might be rot13([srzv]avar). Would've thought rot13(BPG + [srz]ny[r]) made sense, but after OPs comment its clear that the second part of that isn't right.

Comment: @LukasRotter You are on the right track! Try to figure out what “⨂DD” stands for, then take a look at hint 2.

Comment: @Lypyrhythm Huh. The only thing that really makes sense to me is `0xDD`, i.e. hexadecimal for 221. Splitting into digits and taking the nth byte would give `eel`, which is pretty unexpected because an eel is already in the image :). I think I'm still primarily stuck as to what we have to do with primes. Taking the primes of the decimal asciis of the text doesn't seem to give anything interesting.

Comment: @LukasRotter I just added a hint to my question.

Comment: Seems to end rot13("cevzr ryrira 23 (25 -2) [srzv]avar")

Comment: Perhaps the next step is gur agu yrggref sebz gur svefg zrffntr, v.r. ugi?

Comment: @TommyJollyboat rot13(Qvq lbh gnxr n ybbx ng gur 3 flzobyf arkg gb gur zrffntr vpba? Gurl cynl na vzcbegnag ebyr va fbyivat gur chmmyr. Vs lbh ner fghpx, ybbx ng uvag 7.)

Comment: Well done! Please add the geographical coordinates to complete your answer.